# Run different events depending on the outcome of another one

Tags: java

I'm making an API and I've run into this issue where, after an event finishes and if it has been specified, another event will run.

To make this I have a builder to configure the event and this has a "chain" method that allows you to chain one event after another. My problem is that the event can end in 4 different ways: finish, cancel, stop repeating and a timer expires. I'd like to be able to tell the "chain" method to chain different events depending on how the previous event ended but I also want to set one event to several ends of another event.

I though of using an enum with the possible ends to an event and a "CUSTOM" which would allow me to specify what new event I want to run depending on the end of the previous, so for example if event A ends in finish or cancel run event B, if not run event C. However I have been told that all elements in an enum must have the same methods, so my question is: how can I do this?

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Exactly, as per @QBrute. I wouldn't use an enum in this situation if the list of objects were incomplete, and if I did use an enum like this, I wouldn't use those boolean fields. Rather give your burger a `List<Ingredients>` and only add the ones that apply.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It is just an example, I'm not gona use it this example. It is just so you understand what I want

Comment: To be blunt, then it is a very bad example that mainly suggests that you shouldn't be using an enum at all. Better to show a more real-world concrete example of exactly what it is you're trying to do and why.

Comment: But all objects from the same enum must have the same methods, no exceptions. The method body could throw an exception saying that it shouldn't be called, but that's about all you can do.

Comment: @QBrute You are right. I'm making an API and this happends: At a given moment the CUSTOM situarion will apear and I want to be able to modify the ingredients in this situatios but not allow to modify them in the other situatios.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels
I have changed it, now tells exacly what I want. Sorry for the problems

Answer (score 0):

An enum represents a predetermined and finite set of items, such as days of the week or months of the year, or possibly a subset of acceptable choices; there are infinite colors but maybe only 16 you're dealing with.

This being the case, an enum representing the possible event termination states makes sense

```
public enum EventTermination {
    FINISH,
    CANCEL,
    STOP,
    TIMER,
    CUSTOM
}
```

But it wouldn't be the job of the *enum* to "allow me to specify what new event I want to run depending on the end of the previous" — that would be the job of a class, possibly your Event class, each instance of which would hold an EventTermination state and maybe in the case where that state == CUSTOM the *instance* of the class would hold the next event to run.

Using an Interface or possibly a number of interfaces, maybe in a hierarchy, could give you the variability of what methods are available, and maybe there is also an Event hierarchy.

With that, I don't think this question is well suited to Stackoverflow since it can't have a definitive or "correct" answer or even set of answers.
The question *may* be more appropriate for the [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange — but read their help center for what is and isn't expected there.

Comment: In my current project I, in fact, have a whole dual hierarchy of Events and Interfaces that take the general form of `public class SomethingEvent extends EventStub implements SomeEventSubhierarchy` where some other event could extend "SomethingEvent" and implement multiple type-of-event interfaces.